# Existence of ideal in Cohen-Macaulay ring, going modulo which still gives Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay ring of dimension $\le 2$. Does there necessarily exist an ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $\sqrt J$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$ and $R/J$ is Cohen-Macaulay ?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is on hold.

Comment: @Youngsu: I am amazed as well ...